# Laravel 8 custom validation, get @error message in blade view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have two inputs in a blade view from an **array** (each of them for diferent languages) and I build like this:

```html
@foreach ($langs as $lang)
    <input 
        type="text" 
        class="form-control @error('title.{{$lang->isocode}}') is-invalid @enderror" 
        name="title[{{$lang->isocode}}]" 
        id="title[{{$lang->idioma->codi}}]"     
        value="{{ $lang->title }}"
    >
@endforeach
```

My custom [Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation) is this:

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title.*' => ['required', 'string', 'max:100'],
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [            
        'title.*.required' => 'Title is required',
        'title.*.string' => 'Title must be a string',
        'title.*.max' => 'Title is too long',
    ];
}
```

and it works fine. In fact, if I `@dump($errors)`, it shows:

```php
Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag {#353 ▼
  #bags: array:1 [▼
    "default" => Illuminate\Support\MessageBag {#354 ▼
      #messages: array:1 [▼
        "title.ca" => array:1 [▼
          0 => "Title is too long"
        ]
      ]
      #format: ":message"
    }
  ]
}
```

But **the problem is**, if the validations fails, the `.is-invalid` class **is not applied in the input html** tag. I think because `@error('title.{{$lang->isocode}}')` is not correct.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `@error(...)` is a Blade directive, everything inside the parenthesis is PHP, but you are trying to use Blade Echo syntax in there ... just concat the string like you would normally in PHP

Comment: You are right, the correct syntax is `@error('title.'.$lang->isocode) is-invalid @enderror`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  =>title field validation you can use in request method  so remove this .{{$lang->isocode}} that is not correct.@error('title')  print your error message.

class="form-control @error('title') is-invalid @enderror"   
    
    @error('title')
                     <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</div>
     @enderror
```

Comment: I need a different name for each language...

Answer (score 0):

i think the issue you did'nt provide index of error bag :

```
@foreach ($langs as $k=>$lang)
    <input 
        type="text" 
        class="form-control {{$errors->first('title.'.$k.'.'.$lang->isocode)?'is-invalid':''}}" 
        name="title[{{$lang->isocode}}]" 
        id="title[{{$lang->idioma->codi}}]"     
        value="{{ $lang->title }}"
    >
@endforeach
```